Use --replace string in xargs but still use multiple arguments per command
I want to pipe plocate output (a list of paths) to another command using xargs.
I need to use the -I{} replacement but I want to run one single command with all args, not one command per arg.
The problem is that -I option implies -L 1.
Example bash code:
plocate -r '/home/me/.*\.jpg' | xargs -I{} ln {} /tmp/images 

this silly code should link all files found by plocate in /tmp/images.
This actually works but it runs one command per file! which is slow if I have a lot of images.

Perhaps you don't need xargs at all
readarray -t a < <(plocate -r '/home/me/.*\.jpg')
ln -s "${a[@]}" /tmp/images


I choose this answer because it is the most general and  is a simple alternative to xargs

I suggest:
... | xargs echo ln -t /tmp/images

If output looks okay, remove echo.
From man ln:

-t: specify the DIRECTORY in which to create the links


Are you trying to multithread?
-P maxprocs, --max-procs=maxprocs
   Parallel mode: run at most maxprocs invocations of utility at
   once.  If maxprocs is set to 0, xargs will run as many processes
   as possible.

... | xargs -P 0 -I % ln % /tmp/images/ 

